It this a that-clause

But thus it often is, that the constant friction of illiberal minds wears out at last the best resolves of the more generous.

This is from Melville, Bartleby, the Scrivener. I loved the structure "But thus it often is," since in my native language (Turkish) we frequently use a similar phrase (a cognitive pattern, as it were). However, I am confused about the rest of the sentence. Is it a that-clause or what? Can we not just discard "that" and write it like:

But thus it often is, the constant friction of illiberal minds wears out at last the best resolves of the more generous.


Read it as Thus, it often happens/it is often true that...

Melville is not easy to read. Wordy. The word that helps parse the sentence.

But while you may like it, I wouldn't use either construction frequently in English writing. More idiomatic would be "It's often the case that..."

The term that-clause is problematic as this could mark the start of either a relative clause and or a declarative content clause (unmarked finite subordinate clause – one that could stand on its own as 'complete' sentence).

It is him that I saw there.  [relative clause]
It is only that I saw him there. [content clause]

The example given is the latter of the two, a declarative content clause.
As far as whether the that is optional or not, the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language gives the following three examples on p962, the first two of which they claim require that while in the third it's optional.

It's not that I don't understand what you're trying to say.
It's just that there hasn't been time to consider the matter
carefully.
It may be that we should have given him a second chance.

Since there are a variety of other constructions that start with thus it is, it's easy to find instances where there is no that following; however, in the vast majority of cases where it is indeed a content clause that follows, there is a that introducing it. For example, when searching in the News on the Web corpus, the string thus it is that PRONOUN produces 38 hits, all of which have a content clause introduced by that; whereas thus it is PRONOUN has only one hit where the pronoun is in fact the start of a content clause.

Thus it is you are before this court for an extremely serious offence.
(Liverpool Echo)

It would appear that the version with that is heavily favored, though in my personal opinion, the last example would not draw a great deal of criticism.

A clause with so-called nominal status, meaning it can be used rather like a noun-phrase, can stand as the subject of the verb-to-be and other verbs.

That the constant friction of illiberal minds wears out at last the best resolves of the more generous is a fact of life.
That the constant friction of illiberal minds wears out at last the best resolves of the more generous will become clear to you  eventually.

and we can make a cleft from such a sentence enlisting it:

It is a fact of life that the constant friction of illiberal minds wears out at last the best resolves of the more generous.
It will become clear to you eventually that the constant friction of illiberal minds wears out at last the best resolves of the more generous.

